# Pandas Dataframe: number of columns increasing unexpectedly when attempting to select a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I currently have an sklearn RandomForestClassifier, fitted on x_test and y_test and I am now trying to perform predict_proba on a new dataframe new_x containing a single new test datapoint.
I have used getDummies() and Count vectorisers etc so I now need to ensure new_x has the same columns in the **same order** as x_test (there are some columns missing from new_x).
I currently have a function:

```
def addMissingColumns( new_x, x_train ):
     
     new_x=new_x.astype(float)
     x_train=x_train.astype(float)
     missing = set(x_train.columns ) - set( new_x.columns )
 
    #for any columns in x_train not in new_x, add a column of zeros
     
     for m in missing:
         new_x[m] = 0
 
     #take subset of columns that are columns of x_train
    
     new_x=new_x[x_train.columns]
     return new_x
```

which I cant see anything wrong with for the life of me, but it behaves like this:

```
x_train.info()

\>\>\>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 18400 entries, 0 to 18399
Columns: 20080 entries, level_0 to 9999
dtypes: float64(10000), int64(10008), uint8(72)
memory usage: 2.7 GB

new_x.info()

\>\>\><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Columns: 20012 entries, level_0 to 9999
dtypes: float64(10002), int64(10008), uint8(2)
memory usage: 156.5 KB

new_x=addMissingColumns( new_x, x_train )
new_x.info()
\>\>\><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Columns: 40086 entries, level_0 to 9999
dtypes: float64(40016), int64(70)
memory usage: 313.3 KB
```

as you can see, the number of columns in new_x becomes 40086 rather than the expected 20080 (number of columns in x_train)
Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Comment: You'll probably need to include a MRCV (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to have an idea what's going on here. Is there a reason you're fitting the model on test data rather than training data?

Comment: Difficult to answer without a reproducible example. However it could be that you have duplicate column names in either your test or train df. You could check the size of set(df.columns) for both dfs as well?

Comment: @k_n_c the model has been fitted with x_train and y_train and tested with a separate x_test and y_test. In this instance I am simply trying to get the prediction for a new single data point, this is part of a final year uni project involving some extensive feature gathering and preprocessing so I’m not sure giving a reproducible example is really feasible in this situation :(

Comment: @ScootCork I suppose my main source of confusion is how x_new[x_train.columns] can have more columns than x_new under any circumstances?

Comment: In other words, given that the [ ] operator selects a subset of columns in a data frame, how could I be ending up with more columns than before?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate column names? — In the original dataframes, but especially in `addMissingColumns(new_x, x_train)`?

Comment: You're assigning `new_x` back to `new_x`, as well. Just to keep things here, try assigning it to a different variable and reset all your variables / run from scratch.

Comment: @k_n_c It turns out that a part of my Pipeline was introducing duplicate columns, quite hard to spot with so many columns! Removing duplicate columns solved the problem so it was clearly this causing the unexpected behaviour. Thanks all